Google Consent Mode v2 : Tracking info not working on subdomain with url_passthrough
I recently set up Google Consent Mode v2 on my website. I initiate all consent variables to denied but still want to have URL ads tracking data being passed around if the user consents on another page. In order to do this I enabled url_passthrough via my CMP (and I verified that the param gets set properly in GTM preview mode).
My website is set this way :

our content is on mydomain.com (which is equivalent to www.mydomain.com)
we have landing pages on lp.mydomain.com
the app is on app.mydomain.com

Now here is the issue : URLs get decorated correctly if the user arrives on mydomain.com or www.mydomain.com even when the URLs link to a subdomain (like app.mydomain.com for instance).
However if the user lands on a page which is hosted on lp.mydomain.com then the URLs only get decorated when they point to lp.mydomain.com or mydomain.com (not if they point to www.mydomain.com or app.mydomain.com) which makes me lose tracking of a user landing on our LP and being redirected to the app for sign up for instance.
As you can imagine, the vast majority of our ads point to lp.mydomain.com so this is an issue for us.
I have started tinkering around with the window.google_tag_data.gl.decorators object and see that the only domain present there is lp.mydomain.com (or mydomain.com for a page on either www.mydomain.com or mydomain.com). Could this be the issue ? Has anyone experienced this ?
(Note : I can share links to the actual pages if that helps but was not sure if it's authorized)
